# Google Apps Sheets skipping over if statement

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm working on a script for my company so that it can remove duplicate entries. I've been kit-bashing it from an amalgam of sources because I am pretty new to this. This code is **supposed** to create an array of all the non-duplicate entries, clear the whole sheet, and then paste in the array with no duplicates. As it stands it just replaces everything on the sheet with the first cell.

I have found that this:

```
    if(!duplicate){
      newData.push(row);
    }
```

bit of code is not activating at all.

Here is my code as a whole so far:

```
function removeDuplicates(Email, data) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var newData = new Array();
  for(i in data){
    var row = data[i];
    var duplicate = false;
    for(j in newData){
      if(row[Email] == newData[j][1]){
        duplicate = true;
      }
    }
    if(!duplicate){
      newData.push(row);
    }
  }
  sheet.clearContents();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, newData.length, newData[0].length)
      .setValues(newData);
}
```

[image: Image of before and after running the script so far]

**The sheet now looks like the "BEFORE" part both before and after I run the script.**

Again I am new to this, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I guess not then. I think what the original creator of this bit of code I Frankensteined together was trying to do was paste the array "newData" in where the old sheet was. What would you suggest I use instead?

Comment: Actually I just saw my mistake there. I was missing the "s" in "setValues" This brings up a new problem though in that now nothing changes from the old sheet to the new one. Almost like it copied everything regardless of if it was a duplicate. --Updating original post to reflect my changes

Comment: What's with passing in `data`, then reading it from the active sheet? You shadow the argument. If its just like that for testing purposes, i.e. so you can run this function directly from the script editor, you probably want to use `if (!data) data = .....`. And if you're doing that, there isn't a value of `Email` so none of your checks are actually being performed, since `row[undefined]` is `undefined` and `if (undefined == newData[j][1])` will only be true if `newData[j][1]` evaluates to `""`, `0`, `null`, `undefined`, or `false`. Please clarify the steps you have taken to debug this program.

Comment: @JoeHays: It's very good that you share your findings of your continued efforts to find the answer by yourself but as the issue changes the question title should be changed as well the wording of your question. It's a lot better to find at the beginning where are you stuck currently rather than finding that at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working script:

```
FIELDS = {
  FIRST: 0,
  LAST: 1,
  EMAIL: 2,
  EXTRA_STUFF: 3,
};

function removeDuplicates() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Data');
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var newData = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var duplicate = false;
    for (var j = 0; j < newData.length; j++) {
      if (data[i][FIELDS.EMAIL] == newData[j][FIELDS.EMAIL]) {
        duplicate = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (!duplicate) {
      newData.push(data[i]);
    }
  }
  sheet.clearContents();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, newData.length, newData[0].length)
      .setValues(newData);
}
```

Using your data, this is the result:

```
+-------+-------------+----------------------+-------------+
| First |    Last     |        Email         | Extra Stuff |
+-------+-------------+----------------------+-------------+
| Joe   | Hays        | jhays@---.com        | abc123      |
| Joe   | Whitten     | jwhitten@---.com     | abc123      |
| Caleb | Christopher | cchristopher@---.com | abc123      |
| Matt  | Davis       | mdavis@---.com       | abc123      |
+-------+-------------+----------------------+-------------+
```

Some notes regarding what to look out for:

- `FIELDS = {`

  - I like using an object to document the columns as constants
  - this makes reading code that references specific columns easier to read at a glance
  - this is something that could be automated by implementing a function that builds an equivalent object by parsing the first row of the sheet
- `function removeDuplicates() {`

  - there's no need to pass arguments into this functionunderstand at a glance
- `for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {`

  - Loop through the arrays using a variable tracking the index
- `for (var j = 0; j < newData.length; j++) {`

  - the inner loop needs to search through the newData array, to scan it for duplicates
- it may be a good idea to write to another a separate sheet, that way if you run into an unexpected issue, you have the original data easily at your disposal

Comment: I neglected to mention that I had another function that was searching for a column titled "Email" which is where that variable comes from. Regardless, thank you very much! With a little bit of tweaking I was able to make this work flawlessly.